# Problema al crear instancia de RegExp

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex, componentes

Mi problema es el siguiente: Estoy practicando ya que soy demasiado novato en React y me encuentro con el problema que al pasar una expresion regular en el atributo pattern al input me ocurre lo siguiente:

aca como ven, le paso la expresion desde el objeto "expresiones" como atributo al input.

```
const expresiones = {
      usuario: /^[a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]{4,16}$/, // Letras, numeros, guion y guion_bajo
      nombre: /^[a-zA-ZáéíóúàèìòùÀÈÌÒÙÁÉÍÓÚñÑüÜ_\s]{3,16}$/, // Letras y espacios, pueden llevar acentos.
      password: /^.{4,12}$/, // 4 a 12 digitos.
      correo: /^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$/,
      telefono: /\(?([0-9]{3})\)?([ .-]?)([0-9]{3})\2([0-9]{4})/ // 7 a 14 numeros.
    };

    return (
      <section id="contact" className="bg-light text-dark mt-4">
        <div className="container py-3">
          <h3 className="display-3 text-center">Contact Section</h3>
          <hr />

          <form className="row" onSubmit={this.submit} noValidate>
            <Input
              label="Nombre"
              placeholder="Ingresa un nombre"
              type="text"
              nombre="nombre"
              expresion={expresiones.nombre}
            />
```

y esta de aca es lo que conforma el componente Input

```
const label = this.props.label,
      nombre = this.props.nombre,
      type = this.props.type,
      placeholder = this.props.placeholder,
      error = this.props.error,
      expresion = this.props.expresion;

    return (
      <div className="col-8 col-md-6 mx-auto my-2">
        <label className="form-label d-block" htmlFor={nombre}>
          {label}
        </label>
        <input
          className="form-control needs-validation"
          type={type}
          placeholder={placeholder}
          id={nombre}
          pattern={expresion}
          value={this.state.value}
          onChange={this.onChange}
          onKeyUp={this.validar}
        />
```

**Ahora, el detalle es este:** después de un largo rato sin saber qué pasaba con mi validación, se me ocurrió pasarle la expresión regular como una simple cadena a la instancia de RegExp y me fijé que de esa forma si me validaba sin problemas

```
validar = e => {
    let input = e.target,
      regExp = input.pattern,
      valor = input.value;

    let exp = new RegExp(input.pattern),
      exp2 = new RegExp(/^[a-zA-ZáéíóúàèìòùÀÈÌÒÙÁÉÍÓÚñÑüÜ_s]{3,16}$/);

    console.log(exp);
    console.log(exp2);
    console.log(regExp);
  };
```

[image: creacion e impresion de las 3 expresiones regulares]

Como ven, creé 3 variables de 3 formas. Y note que al crear la instancia tal como en "exp2" pero agregando la expresion entre comillas "", el resultado es igual que en "exp", o sea, agrega esos caracteres de mas cuando la imprimo para revisarla. Lo estoy haciendo mal? Mi idea obviamente es crear la instancia tal cual como en "exp" y no ingresarla de forma manual como en "exp2". Debo de alguna forma escapar esas comillas, supongo yo, pero como?
Como dije, el problema es que no me valida de ninguna forma al intentarlo con esa expresion. Solo si uso la forma exp2 me valida

Repito, soy novato, no habia usado esta forma de validar antes, ni trabajado con librerias o frameworks de este estilo, por lo que normalmente haria como dije y pasaria la expresion para cada instancia de RegExp y no tendria problema, creo. Pero ahora me encuentro en esta practica inventando y aprendiendo solo con React y estoy super frustrado. De verdad agradezco inmensamente el tiempo que se tomen en responderme, y tambien si me dan algun consejo de algo mas, igual es bienvenido jaja.

Comment: El código va como texto, por favor

Comment: listo amigo, ya arregle eso. Me parecia mas descriptivo con imagenes pero me fije que solo la ultima era en parte necesaria para mostrar el problema y por eso la deje aunque igual agregue el codigo

Comment: @reynersoto, lo que veo en la consola para `exp` son dos `forward slash` de más al final(//), comparado con el resultado de `exp2`, pero tu dices que son comillas, lo que supongo que quieres hacer es eliminar esos dos` forward slash` de` exp`; no esta claro, ¿Puedes elaborar? Saludos

Comment: no, menciono que al crear la `exp2` pero agregando la expresion regular entre comillas, tambien se vuelve diferente a la que le paso originalmente. Y si te fijas de la `exp` por consola, agrega un slash y un backslash (perdon no me deja agregarlos en codigo) al inicio, y al final me hace un cambio extraño y termino teniendo `$\//` en lugar de lo que deberia ser, un simple `$/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te comparto lo que observé después de revisar el caso.

La propiedad `pattern` del elemento `input`, llega como `string` por medio del `evento`, aunque sigue siendo un objeto `regEx` desde `props`:

```
  validar = e => {
    //aqui hay un String
    console.log(typeof e.target.pattern)
    console.log("e.target.pattern", e.target.pattern)
    //aqui hay un regex object
    console.log(typeof this.props.expresion);
    console.log("expresion", this.props.expresion);
    //codigo...
}
```

Al crear la instancia RegEx con tipo string `e.target.pattern`:

```
let exp = new RegExp(e.target.pattern)
```

se obtiene como resultado el objeto RegEx:

```
/\/^[a-zA-ZáéíóúàèìòùÀÈÌÒÙÁÉÍÓÚñÑüÜ_\s]{3,16}$\//
```

por lo que intente aplicar el método `replace`, para escapar los forward slash:

```
let exp = new RegExp(e.target.pattern.replace(/\//g, ""));
```

Y se obtuvo como resultado el objeto RegEx:

```
/^[a-zA-ZáéíóúàèìòùÀÈÌÒÙÁÉÍÓÚñÑüÜ_\s]{3,16}$/
```

Espero que este análisis sea de ayuda.

Comment: que buena idea, creo que si haria bien el trabajo. El problema es entonces observar como me modifica cada expresion y escapar entonces los caracteres no deseados. No se me habia ocurrido usar el metodo replace. Gracias.